# Error Link 2001 libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) when building any ffmpeg project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ffmpeg

I have just built ffmpeg latest version 3.0 and when I am trying to build ffmpeg related project in Visual Studio 2010, it gives this error:

> libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FreeContextBuffer@4
>
> 1>libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _InitializeSecurityContextA@48
>
> 1>libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__ApplyControlToken@8
>
> 1>libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__FreeCredentialsHandle@4
>
> 1>libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__DeleteSecurityContext@4
>
> 1>libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _AcquireCredentialsHandleA@36
>
> 1>libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DecryptMessage@16
>
> 1>libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EncryptMessage@16
>
> 1>libavformat.a(tls_schannel.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _QueryContextAttributesA@12

My project is able to build an older version from 2014. When I search in 2014 ffmpeg there is no tls_schannel.c present.

But I have to make project now with latest ffmpeg3.0. 
So please tell me how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Above problem is solved by doing following steps:
 i have run command line ./cibfugyre --toolchain=msvc --enable-gpl --disable-network

Then i build again with make command.

Then i included resultant library and headers and my project is running now. 
The problem was i was not doing --disable-network. For that you can do google.

Thank you.

Comment: ./configure --toolchain=msvc --enable-gpl --disable-network  by mistake i have earlier written ./cibfugyre